# How to prevent Rails from rendering links when using partials in Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, mailer, ruby-on-rails-7

I would like to reuse my partials in mailer layouts, but I want to avoid rendering the hyperlinks and instead print out just their name, like using `link_to_if` / `link_to_unless` methods.
Which condition could I check to prevent the rendering all the links inside mailer layouts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your email view, you can use something like this :

```
<%= controller.class.name %>
```

The printed controller name will be a mailer : "ApplicationMailer", ...

You can then Regex or use a string helper ...

Comment: That will work, and I've accepted the answer, but this way the links will appear when I preview my emails (the preview method is defined elsewhere). However I found a simpler solution, i.e. to check for the existence of the `@subject` variable, which is always set in Mailer and preview's controllers, so I can just use  `link_to_unless @subject, product, edit_product_path(@product)` 

Comment: Usually your preview Mailers inherits from `ActionMailer::Preview` and you usually name them `ApplicationMailerPreview` (at least this is how generating the mailer previews with Rspec does). It should be quite easy to filter out also. But glad you found a solution.